# Onclick event with if condition in javascript html

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, buttonclick

pretty new to coding. But I have a small assignment where I just not get what function I should do or how I should write it down. Basicly it should give an input box and a button (this works). But now I want to give an alert IF the input is hi and a different alert if the input is bye. For all other inputs there shouldn't happen anything. I'm just not getting it, can someone help out?

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>

    Input: <input id="welcome1" type="text" />

    <button id="button">Click here</button>
    
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    if (document.getElementById("welcome1").textContent = "hi"){
        document.getElementById("button").onclick = alert("Welcome");
    }
    else (document.getElementById("welcome1").textContent = "bye"){
        document.getElementById("button").onclick = alert("See you later");  
    }

   </script>
```

Comment: `onclick` expects a function. `alert("Welcome")` isn’t a function. In the `if` condition, you should do a _comparison_, not an _assignment_.

Comment: You got it the wrong way around, but you're close! You need only one click handler, than inside that click function - build your logic!

Comment: Aaand don't use onclick like w3schools does, use the proper Element.addEventListener() instead. More on that on a better Docs website like MDN

Answer (score 0):

You should add an event listener to the button, but first you should identify it.
To identify it, you have to use `document.getElementById("the_id")`. Keep in mind that we have other ways to find the element, in other words, we have many selectors (id, class, tag name, etc.).

And when you use an `else` statement, you do not specify another condition. To specify other condition you have to use `else if`, because `else` is for anything that was not in the `if` or an `else if`.

```html
<h1>Welcome</h1>

Input: <input id="welcome1" type="text" />

<button id="button">Click here</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const btn = document.getElementById("button")
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (document.getElementById("welcome1").value === "hi") {
      alert("Welcome");
    } else {
      alert("See you later");
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't notice the single equal sign.

Comment: I corrected a few other things like a stray `</body>`, the formatting on `<h1>`; the `textContent` property should be a `value` property…

Answer (score -1):

## Welcome

```
Input: <input id="welcome1" type="text" >
<button id="button">Click here</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  
  // add eventListener to the element
  document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", handleButton, false)
  
  // function handle to check
  function handleButton () { 
    
    // get the value from the input
    // use querySelector instead of getElementById
    const inputText = document.querySelector("#welcome1").value;

    // check if is the same string and the same type (string)
    if(inputText === "hi") {
      alert ("Welcome");
    } else i f(inputText == "bye") {
      alert("See you later");  
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Add explanation and fix the formatting. The code has syntax errors.